# How do I solve "Incompatible launch template: The network interface's device index must be zero" when updating a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an existing stack that created an auto-scale group that uses a Launch Configuration.  I am now trying to switch this stack so the auto-scale group will use a Launch Template instead of Launch Configuration, but the update is giving this error:

> Incompatible launch template: The network interface's device index
> must be zero. (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error
> Code: InvalidQueryParameter; Request ID:
> 97bdf4cf-5c90-4035-v234-806367461438; Proxy: null)'

The launch configuration defined in the current CloudFormation template sets `AssociatePublicIpAddress: true` and the instance created by this template has a public IP.  The launch template in the CloudFormation template I am trying to use for the update specifies `AssociatePublicIpAddress: true` under `NetworkNetworkInterfaces`.

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

---

Relevant parts of template:

```
  LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: my-launch-template
      LaunchTemplateData:
        EbsOptimized: false
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: !GetAtt MyInstanceProfile.Arn
        ImageId: !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", AMI]
        InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        NetworkInterfaces:
          - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
```

Comment: Can you show your template, or its relevant parts?

Comment: Do you need to explicitly setup `NetworkInterfaces`? If you just remove it, your instance will get public IP anyway if it is launched in a public subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to explicitly set `NetworkInterfaces`, then it should be:

```
  LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: my-launch-template
      LaunchTemplateData:
        EbsOptimized: false
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: !GetAtt MyInstanceProfile.Arn
        ImageId: !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", AMI]
        InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        NetworkInterfaces:
          - DeviceIndex: 0 
            AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
            Groups: [<security-group-id>]
```

Comment: There must still be something going on I don't understand.  I tried it like this, but then it gave this error: "Incompatible launch template: Auto Scaling does not support multiple network interfaces."  I don't see where it is specifying multiple network interfaces.

Comment: @Shawn Can you post the updated version of your template in the question? Nothing else that what I've posted should be required.

Comment: I think the subsequent error was unrelated (I had to change TerminationPolicies: [ OldestLaunchConfiguration ] to be TerminationPolicies: [ OldestLaunchTemplate ] in my auto-scale group).  Ultimately by adding DeviceIndex: 0 it worked for me.

Comment: Trying to use this same config, but to force disabling public IP in public subnet, got "Invalid launch template: When a network interface is provided, the security groups must be
a part of it." Although I can apparently create it through the UI. Is CFN template missing something?

Comment: @Efren Please make new question for your issue with relevant code and errors.

Comment: Posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76070025/1736679